# R legend issue, symbols of points are masked by lines

Tags: r, plot, legend

Is there a way to draw the lines in such a way that they would start on the side of the points, or allow the symbols to be in foreground?

My solution was to make the symbols bigger and more visible.

Edit 1: it's for plot {graphics} of the R program.

Edit 2: the code per popular request.

```
legend(2,.4,bty='n', c('sugar','citrus','none'), pch=c('s','c','u'), pt.bg='white',lty= c(1,2,3), lwd=1.5, title="Condition",pt.cex=c(1.5),cex=1.5)
```

Edit 3: This is solved for plot(type='b') but somehow not for legend.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Not going to down-vote, but you need to specify which graphics system you're using... at minimum!

Comment: Need data and code. This is a coding website for pete's sake.

Comment: Or you could make the lines thinner instead of making the symbols bigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going with the suggestion by @JeffAllen, here is a way to get what I think you might want. It requires modifying the `legend()` function to return the position of the points (these are given by `x1` and `y1` in `body(legend)[[46]]`).

```
legend2 <- legend
body(legend2)[[49]] <- quote(
  invisible(list(rect = list(w = w, h = h, left = left, top = top),
  text = list(x = xt, y = yt), points = list(x = x1, y = y1)))
)
```

Make a plot:

```
plot(-100:100, -100:100, type = "b")
```

While drawing the legend, draw white circles (`pch = 21` with `pt.bg = 'white'`) over the lines, and assign the values invisibly returned by `legend2()` to an object. Note also the changes to `pt.lwd` and `pt.cex`.

```
myLegend <- legend2(1, .8, bty = 'n', c('sugar','citrus','none'), pch = 21,
  pt.bg = 'white', pt.lwd = 0, lty = c(1, 2, 3), lwd = 1.5, title = "Condition",
  pt.cex = c(1.8), cex = 1.5)
```

Finally, draw the characters you'd like to use in the legend using `points()`, supplying the x and y values from the object `myLegend`.

```
points(myLegend$points$x, myLegend$points$y, pch = c('s','c','u'), cex = 1.5)
```

And this should get you something like:

[image: An example plot]

Comment: If I already make a new legend function wouldn't it be easier to ask legend to put the white circles first and then draw the intended symbols.  such as in changing [46] and drawing the white circles before the call for function points2 p.s. Wow, thanks! This is like doing surgery.

Comment: To answer your question and keep the surgical analogy, this would be a minimally invasive solution. If you'd like to perform a more extensive operation and incorporate your suggestion above (and maybe package it up), I think that would be great!

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I can come up with is to manually finagle the dash lengths until they end up looking the way you want them. For instance, this:

```
> plot(1,1)
> legend(c("A", "B"), col = 1:2, x = 1, y = .8, lty="99", pch=1:2)
```

produces the image below.

The `lty` parameter allows you to specify the lengths of lines and dashes as hex characters. In this case, it's saying to create a line of length `9` then create a space of length `9` then repeat. It looks like 9 is about the best fit to space around a normal pch symbol.

Note that you'd probably need to adjust this depending on the size of the image, symbol, etc. My advice ultimately would be to export the image from R and touch up the image to meet your needs in graphic editing software.

[image: graph with manual dash lengths]

Comment: If you really wanted to put the character on the foreground in a reproducible way, you'd probably need to plot a white polygon behind the symbol over the line. In order to do that, you'd probably be best off customizing the `legend()` function to make it meet your needs. It's not a compiled or built-in function, so you can get the source by just typing `legend` and copying that code out into an editor.

Comment: That's a really cool workaround. Not very portable or reproducible (e.g., depends on lwd), but an easy hack for a single legend!

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the filled points offered by R (pch=21:25) and specify the fill color using pc.bg which gets passed to the `points` call when creating a legend.

```
plot(1,1)
legend(c("A", "B"), col = 1:2, x = 1, y = .8, lty=1, pt.bg=1:2, pch=21:22)
```

generates the following:

[image: graph with filled points]