# Legend in R with points and lines

Tags: r, legend

I'm using this command for a legend in R:

```
legend("bottomleft", legend=c("Reale","Smoothing"), col=c("black","red"), lty=1,lwd=2)
```

this gives me a red and a black line. But I need a black point, and a red line. How can i fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add pch symbol in R plot legend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15997121/add-pch-symbol-in-r-plot-legend). And you can use a search engine with this keywords: "R legend point and line".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This could work,

```
legend("bottomleft", legend=c("Reale","Smoothing"), col=c("black","red"), lty=c(1,NA),lwd=c(2,NA),pch=c(NA,1))
```

You can play around with the pch argument to get different shapes